# Запятая после элемента в цикле

Tags: php

Вывожу номера телефонов из массива через запятую, но нельзя ставить запятую после последнего элемента. У меня не выходит самому.

```
end($arElement[PROPERTIES][PHONE][VALUE]);
$last = key($arElement[PROPERTIES][PHONE][VALUE]);
foreach ($arElement[PROPERTIES][PHONE][VALUE] as $phone) { 
echo $phone;
if ($phone != $last) echo ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo implode(', ', $arElement[PROPERTIES][PHONE][VALUE]);` - так?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте, функцию [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php), она для этого и предназначена.

```
echo implode(', ', $arElement[PROPERTIES][PHONE][VALUE]);
```